# command ordering to run a code in C through terminal visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to execute a code on visual studio code, but I don´t want to simply use button or the shortcut, so just like typing on visual studio code terminal "py nameofthefile.py" will execute the code in python, how could I run it on terminal with a command for C programming language?
It's working using the button and shortcut, I just want another alternative.

PS: I do have the correct extensions (C/C++ and C Runner) and compiler (GCC) to run it.

I have tried typing on visual studio code terminal "./nameofthefile.c" and "c nameofthefile.c" in hope any of these would work out.

Comment: at the prompt just type '`./<name of program>`

Answer (score 0):

gcc filename.c -o filename.exe, just ensure you have added the compiler to the system path

Comment: ohh thanks, but now it has another error, this one: 

gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script       
file, or operable program. Check the spelling   
of the name, or if a path was included, verify  
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ oi.exe
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:   
   (oi.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcepti   
  on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundE  
   xception

how could I fix it? I believe it is problem with the path

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/ozU20xxv3Ek